# Trying to count occurrences of a single character line by line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file that I am trying to count occurrences of specific characters line by line. This is the code I'm trying currently and the results I've received. When I use the same code without the file and add part of the data as a string I get the expected result. 
Example piece of a line in the text file = "ADSFABASDFMMASDF"

```
from collections import Counter 

file_handle = open("Input.txt", "r")



protein = file_handle.readlines()


#variable defining for rewrite

proteinout = "" 

for line in protein :
        counted = Counter(protein)
        proteinout += line + str(counted["M"])

print (proteinout)

file_handle.close()


file_handle = open(output.txt", "w")

file_handle.write(proteinout)

file_handle.close()
```

```
Input:
Data1
Data2 
Data3
```

```
Expected Output:
Data1 12 
Data2 25
Data3 38
```

```
Actual Output:
Data1 0
Data2 0
Data3 0
```

Comment: where do the 12, 25, and 38 come from?

Comment: Are you actually counting in the correct strings? Because your output seems to be correct because in the text you posted is no `M`.

Comment: It looks as though you're making the counter out of the wrong thing, your list of lines rather than `Counter(line)`

Comment: Those numbers refer to the expected count of how many times "M" occurs in each line. The zeros refer to the actual output i am getting for the count

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting specific characters in a file (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885930/counting-specific-characters-in-a-file-python)

Comment: Replacing proteinout += line + str(counted["M"]) with proteinout += line + str(counted["M\n"]) as suggested leads to the same output. "Counter(line)" did fix the issue thank you.